# How can I distinguish $_ in nested list operators in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, dictionary

It is often useful to implement algorithms using nested array operations. For example, to find the number of words in a list that start with each given character, you might do something like this in Python:

```
>>> a = ["foo","bar","baz"]
>>> map(lambda c: len(filter(lambda w: w.startswith(c), a)), ('a','b','c','d','e','f'))
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

In the expression `w.startswith(c)` it is trivial to distinguish between the two loop iteration variables `w` and `c` because they have different names.

In Perl, I would like to do something like this:

```
@a = ("foo", "bar", "baz");
map length(grep $_ =~ /^$_/, @a), ('a','b','c','d','e','f')
```

However, the obvious problem with this is that `$_` refers only to the *innermost* `grep` iteration variable (suitable for the `$_` on the left), not the one for the outer `map` (suitable for the `/^$_/`). What is the idiomatic way to avoid this problem in Perl?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just assign to local variable:

```
@a = qw(foo bar baz);
map {my $ch = $_; scalar grep $_ =~ /^$ch/, @a} qw(a b c d e f)
```

Comment: Excellent, that does it. Thanks also for the reminder to use scalar instead of length!

Comment: awesome great fantastic